# adding custom labels to ggplot geom_contour

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a contour plot with specified breaks and labels at those breaks. I tried to add labels at the breaks using either `direct.label` or `geom_dl`, but failed.

```
dat <- melt(volcano)
brks <- c(100, 120, 140, 160)
g <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, z = value)) +
  geom_contour(colour = 'black', breaks = brks)
g
```

That part works fine, but when I try to add the labels:

```
direct.label(g, list("bottom.pieces", colour='black'))
```

I receive the error: `Need colour or fill aesthetic to infer default direct labels.`

And, when I try:

```
g + geom_dl(aes(label = brks),  method = 'bottom.pieces')
```

I get: `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (5307): label, x, y, z`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that I have come to a workaround to show the labels using `geom_dl`:

```
library(lattice)
library(directlabels)
dat <- melt(volcano)
brks <- c(100, 120, 140, 160)
g <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, z = value)) +
     geom_contour(colour='black', breaks = brks)+
     geom_dl(aes(label=..level..), method="bottom.pieces", 
             stat="contour",breaks = brks)
g
```

Just indicate in `geom_dl` that you want to label the levels (`aes(label=..levels..)`) contained in the breaks (`breaks=brks`), so it knows the labels to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I made sure I had the lastest version of directlabels.

And then:

```
dat <- reshape2::melt(volcano)
brks <- c(100, 120, 140, 160)
g <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, z = value)) +
    geom_contour(aes(colour = ..level..), breaks = brks)
g

direct.label(g, list("bottom.pieces", colour='black'))
```